installation problem of APACHE SPARK " The specified path was not found"
I attempted to install Apache Spark by first installing Java and setting the environment variable to 'C:\Java\jdk-11.0.17'. Then, I installed Python and added it to the environment variables. After that, I installed Apache Spark using the spark-3.5.2-bin-hadoop3.tgz file. I also downloaded the winutils file and placed it in the 'bin' folder inside the Hadoop directory. I added the environment variables SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, and JAVA_HOME to the PATH, following the instructions from this tutorial: 'https://medium.com/@deepaksrawat1906/a-step-by-step-guide-to-installing-pyspark-on-windows-3589f0139a30'. However, when I run pyspark in the command prompt, I receive the message 'The specified path was not found.
How to solve this problem ?
